# vuejs repeat static html on @click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure if this is possible in VUEJS.

I want to repeat an element a specific number of times (by passing a number on the `@click` of a button). Please see below sample code:

```
<button @click="function"> where it will tell how many time to repeat
<li v-for="item in (value from btn click)">test</li>
```

when I add code like

```
<li v-for="item in 4">
```

it works but I need this repeat (4) on click of button.

Comment: You can pass a variable instead of a number, check https://forum.vuejs.org/t/noob-question-regarding-v-for-range/25265 | And for the click part, you could initialize that variable to 0, and change it in the click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a number from your button, catch it in a method, and add it to the number you're using to loop. If you want the loop to be one element longer each click, you can pass it `1`.

`<button @click="addToLoop(1)">`

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/56rnv91j/

Comment: valid answer but didn't work on my wearied case which is mix of Jquery and Vue

Answer (score 1):

[`v-for` with a range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range)

> v-for can also take an integer. In this case it will repeat the
> template that many times.

```
<span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }} </span>
```

You can use a `data` item instead of a constant.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    n: 4
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-for="i in n">{{i}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That is working fine with fixed number,. I have conditional statement, if certain parameter will pass it will tell how many times it should repeat. Is there any way, my be like @click I will tell how many time it should repeat?

Comment: Thanks, I have re-phrase my question, please see if it is possible.

Comment: Updated answer. You could have tried this yourself.

Comment: is it possible to update this n value on Jquery click?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: "v-for can also take an integer. In this case it will repeat the template that many times." [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range)

Comment: Thanks, I have re-phrase my question, please see if it is possible.